# SoundCloud totally broken after updating to Windows 8.1 - can't login / can't play sounds with IE11

Tags: soundcloud, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I've updated two computers yesterday to Windows 8.1 and now none of them can play anything through IE 11 on SoundCloud.

I can't even log in!! The annoying human verification window always comes. Then Souncloud signs in for a second and logs me right out again.

I had already load of problem with IE10 and it would only play half of the sounds on SC or stop all together. Sometimes clearing IE cache/cookies would help, only to stop again after minutes.

Why are there so many problems with IE 10/11? IS this not the most used browser and should be a priority that it works?

Windows 8.1 and IE11 is a total nightmare. It seems nothing works with IE11, not even Google Calendar! How can this be the case? The worst update I ever had in a long time, that breaks so many things and actually brings no improvements.

Just noticed that the backup/restore feature is also gone. What are they thinking?

thanks,